# How can I store data into a Dataframe variable within a loop statement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
I write:


 sortstocks['stockCode']=myStock
    sortStocks['ratio']=ratio
```

It doesn't work. More code as blow:

```
 for idx, myStock in enumerate(stockList):
    close=history(myStock, ['close'], 500, '1d', False, 'pre' )
    if len(close)>499:
       ....

       if (MA10Yesterday < MA20Yesterday) and (MA10today > MA20today) and (MA5today> MA10today) and (MA5today < MA58today):
          for i in range(2,500):
              if ...
                 sortstocks['stockCode']=myStock
                 sortStocks['ratio']=ratio
I'm told that sortstocks is not defined, but I have defined in initialize with sortStocks=pd.DataFrame(columns=['stockCode','ratio'])
```

Thanks for Niels' help. Now I rewrite my code as:

```
             sortStocks.loc[idx,'stockCode']=myStock
             sortStocks.loc[idx,'ratio']=ratio
```

When I run it, I get data as below:

```
  0  stockCode     ratio
0     stockCode        NaN       NaN
1         ratio        NaN       NaN
64          NaN  000153.SZ  0.834303
1518        NaN  300171.SZ  0.631573
1774        NaN  300430.SZ  0.662017
```

I want to get output like this:

```
  stockCode     ratio
     000153.SZ  0.834303
     300171.SZ  0.631573
     300430.SZ  0.662017
```

What should I do?

Comment: `It doesn't work.` What happens instead? If you see an error, please provide full traceback [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52688699/edit). Can you provide a **[mcve]**?

Comment: maybe you need initialize sortstocks

Comment: I'm told that sortstocks is not defined, but I have defined in initialize with sortStocks=pd.DataFrame(columns=['stockCode','ratio'])

Answer (score 1):

If your code above is a correct copy of the code you've run, then the error is in a typo in the 3rd last line:

```
sortstocks['stockCode']=myStock
```

should be:

```
sortStocks['stockCode']=myStock
```

(with capital 'S' for ..Stocks)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this problem is not resolved. I update my question.